# How do I render smooth fonts (any "flat" shape really) with OpenGL?

Tags: c++, mesh, blending, opengl-es-3.0

I created the [ftmesh library](https://github.com/m2osw/ftmesh) to draw fonts on my OpenGL ES 3 screen. The code works, but the edges of the characters is raggedy. I'm using an NVidia Jetson AGX Xavier with OpenGL ES 3 and the `glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)` doesn't have any effect (and `glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH)` says *Invalid Enum*—since it's not allowed in ES 2 or 3).

Here is an example of a screenshot showing the ugly edges:

[image]

Is the only option to add an offset edge all around and make the outside part 100% transparent?

Or is there a way to do it with a shader? It would be fantastic to get a link to an example.

My current shader just transmits the vertices as is:

```
varying vec4 polygon_color;

attribute vec2 in_position;
attribute vec4 in_color;

void main()
{
    polygon_color = in_color;
    gl_Position = vec4(in_position.xy, 0, 1);
}
```

And here is the fragment shader:

```
varying vec4 polygon_color;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = polygon_color;
}
```

I set all the `in_color` vertices to `(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.75f)` before the `glDrawArrays()` call.

### Sample Buffers (Solution)

As suggested by Rabbid76 in a comment, I tried adding multisampling. It has an effect, it created a form of *grid*, though... much more transparent than expected (see picture below).

1. In my `g_egl_visual_attributes` I added `EGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS` like so:

   ```
    constexpr EGLint const g_egl_visual_attributes[] =
    {
        EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
        EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
        EGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, 1,   // <-- added this option
        EGL_SAMPLES, 8,          //     and this one
        EGL_NONE,
    };
   ```

   Note: with my configuration, `EGL_SAMPLES` of 16 doesn't work (no such buffer available).
2. Then I enabled the sample alpha coverage

   ```
    glEnable(GL_SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_COVERAGE);
    glEnable(GL_SAMPLE_COVERAGE);
   ```

   But that had the side effect shown below...

   [image]
3. So I tried without the `glEnable()` calls and now that works as expected]!

   If you look closely, in this last image we can see the anti-aliasing on the edges:

   [image]

   So MSAA resolved the issue.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the letter is drawn by a polygon. What about [Multisampling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Multisampling)?

Comment: I actually use the `GL_TRIANGLES` because ES does not have the notion of polygons. This is why I had to use a library that generates a mesh. It supports `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` and `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`, but at this time I avoid those. I would think, anyway, that this would give a similar result.

Comment: `GL_TRIANGLES` is polygon primitiv. There are points, lines and polygons (like triangles - see [Primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive)). So you re drawing triangles. Read about [Multisampling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Multisampling).

Comment: @Rabbid76 Okay! I was able to make it work simply by adding `EGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, 1,` to the visual attributes! Thank you for the pointers.

Comment: Is using pre-rendered textures an option?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I already have such, but it's actually very slow to generate many strings and then render that texture. So that's why I create the ftmesh project to get the triangles. And that uses just a few % of the CPU.

Comment: The state of the art is to use a texture atlas that stores every glyph, and render text using those. And instead of just a bitmap image of each glyph, a signed distance field (SDF) can be used to even make it look good when zooming in and out. See: https://github.com/Chlumsky/msdfgen

Answer (score 1):

A much nicer anti-aliasing is provided by the library FreeTypeGL, but it renders the characters in a completely different manner, by means of a distance map, and as a side effect it doesn't make perfect corners:

https://github.com/rougier/freetype-gl

Comment: That looks like a fine piece of code, but I'm wondering about speed now... my solution just added a tad bit of EGL code, the library you reference would be huge in comparison.